# Filtering a JSONArray depending on a second JSONArray

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am receiving two JSONArrays from a web service.

The first JSONArray has 32 items.

The second JSONArray has 7 items.

I need to filter the first JSONArray comparing some values from it with some values from the second JSONArray, and then I want to populate a recyclerview with the filtered items from the first JSONArray.

The filter should give only 5 from the 32 items.

The current result is giving me a recyclerview with 32 items, 27 of them are empty and the other 5 are showing the needed filtered items.

The way I am trying to get the filtered items is using two loops.

The first loop is including all item from the first JSONArray and at each loop I have included a second loop with all items from the second JSONArray. Then I have created two if clauses with the conditions that should filter the desired items. Then I am adding the filtered items to the List that should populate the recyclerview.

I am sure that this is not a very clean method to filter a JSONArray depending on the values of a second JSONArray, but obviously this method is filtering the first JSONArray as needed. The issue is that I am not able to populate the recyclerview with the resulting items.

This is what I have for now:

```
public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL_SEARCH(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            UsuariosBuscarAmigos GetDataAdapter2 = new UsuariosBuscarAmigos();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);


                //array de amigos


                                try {

                                    String amigosArray = prefs.getString("amigosArray","");



                                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(amigosArray);

                                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {


                                        JSONObject amigos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);



                                        String amigo_1 = amigos.getString("amigo_1");
                                        String amigo_2 = amigos.getString("amigo_2");
                                        String usuario_id = json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_01);


                                            if (mi_id.equals(amigo_1) && usuario_id.equals(amigo_2)  ){



                                                GetDataAdapter2.setid(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_01));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setusername(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_02));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setprofile_image(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_03));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setuser_type(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_04));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setcity(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_05));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setdeportes(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_06));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setcountry(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_07));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setabout(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_08));
                                            }



                                            if (mi_id.equals(amigo_2) && usuario_id.equals(amigo_1)){


                                                GetDataAdapter2.setid(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_01));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setusername(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_02));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setprofile_image(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_03));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setuser_type(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_04));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setcity(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_05));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setdeportes(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_06));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setcountry(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_07));
                                                GetDataAdapter2.setabout(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_08));
                                            }

                                        }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }




            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            subjectsList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

            recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAmigosMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter(subjectsList, getActivity());


        }


        recyclerViewPosts.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);


    }
```

EDIT

Screenshot showing part of the items, including one of the 5 filtered items.

[image]

LOG from subjectsList:

```
for(int i = 0; i<subjectsList.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("subjectsList","subjectsList item#:"+i+">"+subjectsList.get(i).id+" "+subjectsList.get(i).username);
        }

D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:0>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:1>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:2>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:3>72 anasimo
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:4>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:5>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:6>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:7>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:8>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:9>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:10>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:11>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:12>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:13>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:14>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:15>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:16>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:17>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:18>70 mov-map-TR
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:19>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:20>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:21>null null 
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:22>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:23>99 movmapgmail
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:24>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:25>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:26>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:27>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:28>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:29>71 qweqweewq
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:30>null null
D/subjectsList: subjectsList item#:31>null null
```

Comment: So did you check to see if data is being added to subjectsList?

Comment: @svi.data, yes, what I have detected is that all items from the first array are added to subjectsList, that means that the size of subjectList is 32. On the other hand, the 5 filtered items are shown with all their data, the other 27 items are empty but added to subjectList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**keep this:**

Okay since all the data are in the list there is no problem with the JSON filtering.

I assume that the problem is you are creating a new adapter in the for loop which resets the data in the adapter.

So move this line:

```
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAmigosMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter(subjectsList, getActivity());
```

and put it directly above this:

```
 recyclerViewPosts.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
```

This way you dont recreate the adapter for each loop.

**update:**

The problem is that you are creating a new object in the wrong place, this is why you always get 32 objects, so remove this:

```
UsuariosBuscarAmigos GetDataAdapter2 = new UsuariosBuscarAmigos();
```

from here:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

    UsuariosBuscarAmigos GetDataAdapter2 = new UsuariosBuscarAmigos();

  .....
```

and put here in your first if statement:

```
  if (mi_id.equals(amigo_1) && usuario_id.equals(amigo_2)  ){

    //create object here  
    UsuariosBuscarAmigos GetDataAdapter2 = new UsuariosBuscarAmigos();

     GetDataAdapter2.setid(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_01));      

     ............

    //add it to list

    subjectsList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

}
```

and in the other if statement do the same:

```
if (mi_id.equals(amigo_2) && usuario_id.equals(amigo_1)){

//create object here
UsuariosBuscarAmigos GetDataAdapter2 = new UsuariosBuscarAmigos();

GetDataAdapter2.setid(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_01));
....
...

//add it here

subjectsList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

}
```

finally remove this:

```
subjectsList.add(GetDataAdapter2);
```

from here:

```
......
} catch (JSONException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
 }

//remove this
subjectsList.add(GetDataAdapter2);
.......
```

Comment: I have implemented your proposal, but the same result. 27 empty rows and 5 correct rows.

Comment: The 27 empty rows are populated in the recycler view?

Comment: Do you see 27 empty rows and can scroll through them?

Comment: yes, the 27 rows are empty, visible and scrollable. I will put a screenshot to show you the final result

Comment: okay print the log for the subjectsList, and see if all the data are filled, I mean check to see if all the variables for your objects have values in the subjectsList.

Comment: So if I understand right your needed result should be only 5 items right?

Comment: I have included the log for subjectsList

Comment: Yes, I need to only show the 5 filtered items, not the 32.

Comment: I expected that okay I think I know whats going on, just wait so I update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but implementing your proposal I am getting no results.

Comment: you have to get results, please implement everything the way that I told you, the idea i to create a new object and set the values and add it to the list in the if-statement not at the begining of the for loop like you did.

Comment: you are right, it is working now, thank you for your time and effort